# How to connect a USB only printer to router without USB port via a USB to ethernet adapter?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, ethernet, network-printer, usb-2

I have Cisco Linksys router which does not have a USB port and a [USB to ethernet adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005DDI51U); picture below.

When I try to connect the printer to the router using the adapter the router does not shows the device in its webpage.

Can anybody help me?

I am using two different Windows 7 systems which are connected to the Wi-Fi router and I want to share the printer between them.

[image]

Comment: The problem may not be you.  If you look at the reviews for the adapter, half of the purchasers had an unsatisfactory experience.  It's among the worst product reviews I've seen for anything.  Before you invest a lot of time trying to tweak the system, I would just get another adapter.

Comment: That silly adapter will not do what you want it to. It does not convert USB connections to Ethernet connections because it has no electronics in it. Without looking too hard at the listing it seems like the main purpose of this dongle is to allow you to extend a USB connection with Ethernet cabling. It will _not_ convert Ethernet packets to USB protocol and the other way around since there are utterly no electronics in this cable. So you need to get an actual USB to Ethernet print server [as explained in posted answer](https://superuser.com/a/872234/167207).

Comment: Way late to this, but no that adapter will not work for you.  Those adapters are for devices that are *specifically* designed to use them.  They are not general purpose adapters.  There are no electronics in them to convert to/from ethernet and USB.  There are - or were - devices to convert USB to wired ethernet, as well as WiFi.  However, i havent seen them in ages... granted this post is ancient.  Get a Raspberry Pi or cheap pc and just use it as a print server.  Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

USB adapters are usually very job-specific. The one you linked is designed to connect a USB **modem** to a network. That will not work with anything else.

There are adapters (called "printservers") that are designed to connect a USB printer into a network. They usually work on condition that you *only use them with the printer(s) they're designed for*. Most reputable suppliers have a list of the printers their models are compatible with. Examples include [DLINK](http://files.dlink.com.au/Products/DPR-1020/REV_A/SetupGuides/DPR-1020_Multifunction_Printer_Compatibility_List.pdf), and here is the [compatibility list](http://files.dlink.com.au/Products/DPR-1020/REV_A/SetupGuides/DPR-1020_Multifunction_Printer_Compatibility_List.pdf) for one of their models.

Most USB printers are what's called GDI or host-based printers. They have very little built-in intelligence and depend on the Windows graphics engine to convert the page into dots on the page. These printers are also very hard to network. The easiest way to do so is to plug them into one PC and share it. That will always work, but it means the sharing PC has to be on before anyone can print.

Comment: that's what i have done but to stop unnecessary power consumption which I require in order to keep host machine on I was trying to network the printer to router.

Comment: Try searching the web for a printserver that supports your printer. If you tell me the printer model I can have a look for you.

Comment: its "epson 2175 FX"

Comment: I've looked at compatibility lists for DLink, TP-Link, Lantronix, Netgear, Linksys and Belkin, but your printer does not show up with any of them. I'm afraid you may be out of luck.

Comment: I know this an old question. I just noticed it now. In case you're still dealing with the problem. Using a generic print-server box will normally work as long as it support a generic IBM/Epson compatible printer. If your printer still has an old-school Parallel or serial interface it is 100% certain it will work if you use a print-server box that can connect to that.

Comment: Just adding my two cents here: This USB to Ethernet adapter works for USB modems since those USB modems are wired to allow the USB connection to become Ethernet; it is not some kind of generic USB functionality. Simple as that. And as such, this dongle will not ever do what the original poster wishes it to do. A print server is the only realistic option to allow the original poster to connect a USB printer to their router.